# Line of jQuery code not working - Broken somewhere?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is part of an assignment. When I click on international, the slide down id should activate a sub menu, however it's not working. Any suggestions?

I've double checked the file links on the HTML

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('primary-nav .international').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $( "#primary-nav .international" ).siblings().removeClass("active");
        $( "#primary-nav .international").toggleClass("active");

        if($( "#primary-nav .international" ).hasClass('active')) {
            if($("#slide-down").hasClass('open')) {
                $('#slide-down .drop.open').hide().removeClass('open');
                $('.drop.international').show().addClass('open');
            } else {
                $('#slide-down .drop').hide();
                $('.drop.international').show().addClass('open');
                $('#slide-down').slide-down(150).addClass('open');
            }
        } else {
            $('#slide-down').slideup(150).removeClass('open');
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: `$('primary-nav .international')` right there

Answer (score 0):

typo on the third line

```
$('primary-nav .international')
```

should be

```
$('#primary-nav .international')
```

based on the rest of the code

edit: also, you should probably cache some of those selectors to make your code more readable, less prone to typos, and faster (if even just a little).  for instance:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#primary-nav .international').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var obj = this;
        $(obj).siblings().removeClass("active");
        $(obj).toggleClass("active");

        if($(obj).hasClass('active')) {
            if($("#slide-down").hasClass('open')) {
                $('#slide-down .drop.open').hide().removeClass('open');
                $('.drop.international').show().addClass('open');
            } else {
                $('#slide-down .drop').hide();
                $('.drop.international').show().addClass('open');
                $('#slide-down').slide-down(150).addClass('open');
            }
        } else {
            $('#slide-down').slideup(150).removeClass('open');
        }

    });
});
```

that kind of thing

you can also do things like this

```
$('.some-child-of-obj', obj)
```

giving your selectors a little context.

Comment: If you're going to cache selectors, it might be a good idea to do the jQuery variable.  `var obj = $(this);`

Comment: true.  That'll make it a faster still I suppose.  I guess it's just force of habit for me to work mostly with the elements themselves rather than the jQuery object.  I've almost completely dropped use of jQuery of late in favor of vanilla or other frameworks, so it's easy for me to forget that jQuery doesn't extend elements.

Comment: Yeah, I understand.  Just a heads up to OP, I think it's a good rule-of-thumb to have jQuery variables start with a `$` so you don't confuse it for an actual HTML element.  `$someVar = $('.some-selector');`